# How do I prevent my Thunderbolt Display from blinking repeatedly?

Tags: thunderbolt-display

I use an Apple Thunderbolt Display with my Late 2011 Macbook Pro, and more often then not when I plug it in, one of a few video errors will occur.

The most frequent issue is that the display will blink anywhere from once every second or three, to once every 10-20 seconds. It is severely annoying, and my only solution so far is to unplug and plug the display back in until the lock screen no longer blinks. It usually takes at least twice to stop, sometimes more.

I've theorized that this is related to static buildup. I dock my Macbook Pro (clamshell mode / closed lid) into a [BookArk](http://www.twelvesouth.com/products/bookarc/), which is placed on a white top desk that sometimes feels staticy when brushing my hand across the surface of the desk. The display itself is on a glass desk physically separated from the opaque white-top desk.

Is there something I should do to mitigate static buildup? Or is this a symptom of some other issue?